# Error when create a instance of WebService

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a WebService that when I use the instance of this webservice, occurs the following error

```
// Instance of WebService
ServicoZap.EnvArqSenhaSoapClient envia = new ServicoZap.EnvArqSenhaSoapClient();
```

Error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'Contract Name' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This
>   might be because no configuration file was found for your application,
>   or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found
>   in the client element.

In my app.config the reference is OK.

But to test the webservice, I'm using another project in my solution, called Test.

In this project (Test), I don't have an app.config (I don't know if was necessary).

Can help me ?

Comment: Read this, it might help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/863/Your-first-C-Web-Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the app.config in the test project too in this case - copying it over to the test project is one way to fix this

Comment: but this will impact in my Test project. This project has a lot of button in a Window Form. I just call anothers projects in all click buttons in this forms, just for test. With a app.config will impact something ?

Comment: If you have no app.config in the project, adding an app.config will not cause any problems